# Roxygen2 skipps .Rd generation

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

As the title says, I have a problem generating **R** package documentation with **roxygen2**. 
I am 99.9% positive to have prepared everything as explained [here](http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) [and here](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/docs.html) already. I know it is almost impossible to get an answer to a prime remote diagnosis-nono-case like this, but I have to give it a shot.

Here is what I see after using `document()`

```
> document()
Updating mypack documentation
Loading mypack 
Writing NAMESPACE
There were 7 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: fun1.Rd not generated by roxygen2. Skipped.
2: fun2.Rd not generated by roxygen2. Skipped.
...
```

It seems that I have installed `devtools` and `roxygen2` correctly - no errors with that.

If it is of importance: I have several .R files with several functions inside, but all functions do have a description.

To make sure and verify a strange behaviour, I used the exact examples of both pages - those were skipped too. What could be wrong here? Wild guessing is okay at this point.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This warning](https://github.com/yihui/roxygen2/blob/master/R/utils.R#L96) typically occurs because the `.Rd` files already exist in the `man` directory (did you create them manually, perhaps in an earlier version of your project?). roxygen2 doesn't replace them if they don't start with a line indicating they were auto-generated, along the lines of:

```
% Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.0): do not edit by hand
```

To solve this, delete the `.Rd` files in the `man` directory, then re-run `document()`.

Comment: Quick comment/question: I am first developing a package and, when I first ran devtools::document, it did NOT giving me this warning and had a comment ``First time using roxygen2 4.0. Upgrading automatically...'' in the output. I only had the "skipped" issue in the question when I added comments to my second function and ran devtools::document the second time

Comment: @gvrocha Ah, good to know. Did deleting the files work after that?